# "lines-between-class-members" ESLint Error When Declaring Class Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

As I like the `"lines-between-class-members"` rule, **I'd like to enforce spaces between my classes' functions**, but in the same time I want the properties declarations packed at the beginning of my classes in the following format:

```
class Foo {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: string;
  d: string;

  constructor() {
    // constructor stuff
  }

  doSomething() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Is there a way to ignore this rule specifically on types declarations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems like you'll have to do this

```
'lines-between-class-members': [
  'error',
  'always',
  { 'exceptAfterSingleLine': true },
]
```

[Docs](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members.md#options) It will skips checks for empty lines after a single-line class member.

Comment: Given the flexibility this rule provides this is probably the best one can do. But bear in mind that this rule will not trigger if you will not have empty line between last class field and constructor as class field is a single line member

Comment: This exception leads to a lot of weirdness if you have many properties that are longer than a single line - more common when we have Prettier also enforcing a line-length. It'll enforce a line break after but not before the property, leading to random looking gaps. It's not very intuitive why unless you go crawling in the settings for this exception.

Answer (score -3):

add the rule into the **.eslintrc.js**

lines-between-class-members: ["error", "never"]

also, this link will be more helpful: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/lines-between-class-members

Comment: I'd like to enforce spaces between my classes' functions

Answer (score -3):

Please add this hopefully it will work:

> `/* eslint-disable no-trailing-spaces */`

Comment: Thank you, but this is a very manual solution, in contrary to the working pattern with eslint